# onChange is not functioning because of getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to avoid using `componentWillReceiveProps` and im using `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

It does update the state with the values, however the onChange function is not functioning.

onChange is being called, but im unable to type in the fields.

Just to give an idea, component gets edited data, and user is able to edit their information

**editProfile.tsx**

```
class EditProfile extends Component<dashboardProps, dashboardState> {
  state: dashboardState = {
    bio: "",
    gravatar: ""
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserProfile();
  }
  // deprecated
  // componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  //   this.setState({
  //     bio: nextProps.user.bio,
  //     gravatar: nextProps.user.gravatar
  //   });
  // }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.user !== prevState.user) {
      return { bio: nextProps.user.bio, gravatar: nextProps.user.gravatar };
    }
    return null;
  }

  handleChange = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    } as any);
    console.log(e.target.name);
  };
  .........
}
```

Comment: You can check and see if this solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682297/how-can-i-make-my-input-field-prefilled-with-data-and-editable-on-page-load/58837912#58837912
Basically I've added a state called `prevProps` and you use the `prevProps` state to compare and update your state according. ( Without using `componentWillReceiveProps` )

Comment: ok will look into this. thank you.